# HTML overwrite SAP CSS styles

Tags: html, css

I want to add a table to an SAP website, but I can't seem to make it look good in any way, because the website simply removes any styles. Padding, margin and so on are simply removed somehow.

```
<table style="width:1024px;font-family:arial;border-spacing: 5 5" cellpadding="5px">
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#005028" height="40"><font color="white" size="4"><b>First Aid</b></font></td>
    <td bgcolor="#005028"><font color="white" size="4"><b>Phone</b></font></td>
    <td bgcolor="#005028"><font color="white" size="4"><b>Security Officer</b></font></td>
    <td bgcolor="#005028"><font color="white" size="4"><b>Phone</b></font></td>
    <td bgcolor="#005028"><font color="white" size="4"><b>Fire Protection</b></font></td>
    <td bgcolor="#005028"><font color="white" size="4"><b>Phone</b></font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#D3D3D3" height="30">name</td>
    <td bgcolor="#D3D3D3" height="30">111</td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="30">name</td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="30">111</td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="30">name</td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="30">111</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#D3D3D3" height="30">name</td>
    <td bgcolor="#D3D3D3" height="30">111</td>
    <td bgcolor="#D3D3D3" height="30">name</td>
    <td bgcolor="#D3D3D3" height="30">111</td>
    <td bgcolor="#D3D3D3" height="30">name</td>
    <td bgcolor="#D3D3D3" height="30">111</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

this is looking like i want it to, besides the fact, that it has no padding or any margins. i tried it with CSS, but this gets completely removed. I had a conversation with someone who was able to overwrite it with `!important`, but this didn't work for me.

```
<style>
table{
    width: 1024px!important;
    font-family: arial!important;
    padding: 5px!important;
    border-collapse:separate!important; 
    border-spacing:4px!important;
}

td.head{
    background-color:#005028!important;
    height:40px!important;
    padding: 5px!important;
    color: white!important;
    margin: 5px!important;
}
tr{
    background-color:#D3D3D3!important;
    height:30px!important;

}
td.phone{
    width: 70px!important;
    padding: 5px!important;
    margin: 5px!important;

}
td.name{
    width: 245px!important;
    padding: 5px!important;
    margin: 5px!important;
}

</style>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="head"><font color="white" size="4"><b>First Aid</b></font></td>
    <td class="head phone"><font color="white" size="4"><b>Phone</b></font></td>
    <td class="head"><font color="white" size="4"><b>Security Officer</b></font></td>
    <td class="head phone"><font color="white" size="4"><b>Phone</b></font></td>
    <td class="head"><font color="white" size="4"><b>Fire Protection</b></font></td>
    <td class="head phone"><font color="white" size="4"><b>Phone</b></font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="name">name</td>
    <td class="phone">111</td>
    <td class="name">name</td>
    <td class="phone">111</td>
    <td class="name">name</td>
    <td class="phone">111</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="name">name</td>
    <td class="phone">111</td>
    <td class="name">name</td>
    <td class="phone">111</td>
    <td class="name">name</td>
    <td class="phone">111</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Any suggestion is appreciated. I am not that good in html and since my css try was a complete disaster, i would like to stay in plain html

Comment: on the webpage are there any css reference script tags and can you access those files? Long shot......but have you uploaded your changes, cleared web cache then tried to reload?

Comment: @brad i have no access to any of the files. they are completely out of reach. the problem is that i can't upload my table as file, but have to paste it in an editor of the website which interprets it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use more specifics when calling your CSS changes. Instead of using `table`, name the elements using ids and classes and call those instead. CSS sets priority based on specificity. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) is an informative write-up on it.

An Alternative for Firefox users is their HTML [Style Scoped](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_style_scoped.asp) feature.

```
<div>
<style scoped>
h1 {color:red;}
p {color:blue;}
</style>
<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

[Here](https://css-tricks.com/saving-the-day-with-scoped-css/) is a bit more documentation on it.

Comment: i was able to do it with the scoped style in the end. thanks for the tip!

Comment: Glad to help. Sorry that I didn't make the Firefox caveat more clear.

Comment: no problem. looks like its working in other browsers as well, even tho the internet says they don't support it (or they just ignore the scoped part)

Comment: I believe for non FF browsers (except IE), the styling will work, but it may be applied to the whole page instead of just that section. Not sure if you saw this page from FF that shows basic support compatibility: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope .

Comment: now i saw it and chrome does not support it. the whole field is lime xD, but my table works (its only the table on the page) and thtas good